# How do I remove a git repository from my computer while keeping the online version?

Tags: git

I'm somewhat of a beginner with git, is there a good way to remove the local repository but keep my github backup? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Upload all the content to your remote
- Delete the local folder.

---

```
# upload all tags, branches to your remote
git push origin --all

# delete the local folder
git rm -rf .
```